# How to change a property of a html element that was execute in php with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Before you guys go mad saying they cant communicate as one is executed in client and the other on server side. Im asking for an alternative or how do i go to fix the issue I have. I have a div inside a variable in php, which I then echo this variable in the html. I done this because this div has to be dynamic, it could be implemented only once to the page to 100s depending on the user. Therefore I figure having one div inside a php loop that gathers all the information and displays it on the html would be code efficient, the information passed to the div are information from a cookie therefore I do need to use php as well as communicating to the server. however I now need to edit that div with javascript and im not sure if that is possible or how to go on about doing it. I read into ajax or HTTPREQUEST and I dont think thats what I need.

UPDATED

The div contains information of a product, that product should be deleted if user press the img below "delete" I need a validation that deletes the div. I think that will need to be done in javascript.

PHP

```
for($temp = 1; $temp <= $cArray[2]; $temp++)
 {
 $img .= "<div class='boxChildLeft'> 
      <div class='img'>
      <img src='../ProductImages/$cArray[0].jpg' width='100px'height='100px'>
       </div>
       <div class='prodInfo'>
             <p1>$pName</p1><br>
        </div>
        <span id='sp'>
           <p1>$pPrice<p1><br><br>
            <img src='../delete.png' width='30px' height='30px' style='opacity: 0.5'>
           //I need a javascript code that once user has hover over 
            //this img the opacity level changes from 0.5 to 1
            </span>
           </div>";
          }
```

HTML

```
 <div id="box">
       <?php echo $img;?>

 </div>
```

Comment: _I now need to edit that div with javascript_ which type of edit you want? Explain

Comment: why dont you pass the div to a javascript variable, modify it and then add to the DOM?

Comment: The img opacity is 0.5. once the user hover over the image I want the img opacity to be 1. I think i need javascript for that no?

Comment: I put a comment on the code that says what I need

Comment: You don't need javascript for that. You can do that with CSS. img:hover { opacity: 1; }

Comment: yes using javascript you can do this.

Comment: How do i pass the div to a javascript variable from php? I need the variable on php as it has to communicate to the server first and also gather the relevant cookies

Comment: Thanks Gerand. I will try adding that, but for the sake of this question lets say I need to modify the div inside a php variable as shown above, how would I go on to do it?

Comment: If you are using jquery you can get image element like : `$("#box .boxChildLeft .img img")`

Comment: Don't use jQuery for a simple hover effect CSS3 can do easier. Just do `#box .boxChildLeft .img img: hover { opacity:1; }` and set the initial non-hover state to `opacity: 0.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments to your post.

You can merely write a js function at your view template php file that you are finally rendering.

If you are worrying about the DOM - do not, - element you are passing within php data will already be there in the DOM.

If you are asking about the js script itself, not knowing what to do, - try something at least, and add the code to your post, then you would be reviewed and advised, or maybe even provided with a right solution.

Clue: use `document.querySelectorAll`, `.forEach()`, `.remove()` functions and `.mouseover`, `.click` callbacks for instance

And as @Gerard stated, if you need precisely that and nothing more, than you could use simple css styling.

Comment: I updated the questions with this "The div contains information of a product, that product should be deleted if user press the img below "delete" I need a validation that deletes the div. I think that will need to be done in javascript." Im not sure where to begin the code how to gather the user input.

Comment: ok, you are free to act, - do smth, so we could review what you are doing wrong

Comment: Its easier than I thought, I can just create a onclick="function" inside the div, and that will call the javascript function once clicked. I was expecting to be harder hahaha.

Comment: well done, now you can answer your own question and mark it as a correct one